# Run onchange event react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to run an `onChange` event on a `select-react` component, but I cannot change the default values.
In addition to changing the options, I need to assign the selection values ​​to a `state`.
When I remove the `state`, I am able to change the options normally.

I saved the code at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-tu-1ituy?file=/src/App.js:120-1034) for verification.

```
const options = [
  {
    label: "Queue 1",
    value: 0
  },
  {
    label: "Queue 2",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: "Queue 3",
    value: 2
  }
];

const defaultOptions = [
  {
    label: "Queue 1",
    value: 0
  },
  {
    label: "Queue 3",
    value: 2
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const [selectedQueue, setSelectedQueue] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = async (e) => {
    const value = e.map((x) => x.value);
    console.log(value);

    // if you comment the two lines, below I have no problems
    setSelectedQueue(value);
    console.log(selectedQueue);
  };

  const CustomSelect = (props) => (
    <Select
      options={options}
      defaultValue={defaultOptions}
      className="custom-select"
      onChange={handleChange}
      {...props}
    />
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Multiselect:
      <CustomSelect isMulti />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are recreating `CustomSelect` component on each render, which means that the component is remounted on each render, and the `defaultValue` is applied again. Extract the component out of the `App` component ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-wilbur-8uvv5)):

```
const CustomSelect = (props) => <Select className="custom-select" {...props} />;
```

And pass the props to the component, when you render it in `App`:

```
const App = () => {
  const [selectedQueue, setSelectedQueue] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = async (e) => {
    const value = e.map((x) => x.value);
    console.log(value);

    // if you comment the two lines, below I have no problems
    setSelectedQueue(value);
    console.log(selectedQueue);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Multiselect:
      <CustomSelect
        options={options}
        defaultValue={defaultOptions}
        onChange={handleChange}
        isMulti
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I only have one question!
What if `options` and `defaultOptions` are also inside the` App` component?
This data comes from the API, right when the component is loaded with `useEffect`

Comment: Pass it as props to the `CustomSelect`. Look at the sandbox, and I'll expand the example here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't help noticing that the state is late. while `console.log` shows 1, the state `selectedQueue` shows 0. and when `console.log` shows 2, `selectedQueue` shows 1. what can I do? I know that the state is asynchronous, but I lack the knowledge to get around it.

Comment: The state would only update the next render. Move the `console.log()` to the body of the component.

Comment: Here I have something related to this problem, help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607037/update-usestate-immediately