# react-electron ipcRenderer in useEffect does not rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron

I'm trying to make a global accessible object, so that its values can be changed and can be read from every component. I've create a classs with static fields:

```js
export default class Settings {
  static first: string;

  static second: string;
}
```

Lets say I have two components in separate files:

```js
import Settings from './Settings'

// located in firstComponent file
export default function FirstComponent() {
Settings.First = 'test'    <---------------- SET VALUE
return (some html)
}

// located in secondComponent file
export default function SecondComponent() {
let qq = Settings.First <----------------------- ASSUME HERE IS VALUE "TEST"
}
```

But it is not working. How I can create static class/fields that will be accessible within all components like C# static classes. Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance

**UPD**
Looks like the problem in ipcRenderer:

```
export default function SettingsEditor() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    ipAddress: Settings.ipAddress,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    electron.ipcRenderer.once('readSettings', (args) => {
      console.log('Filling settings');
      console.log(args); <------ HERE WE HAVE VALUE like 10.10.10.10
      setState({ ...state, ipAddress: args.ipAddress});
      console.log(state.ipAddress); <------ UNDEFINED
      state.ipAddress = args.ipAddress;
      console.log(state.ipAddress); <------ UNDEFINED
      Settings.ipAddress= args.ipAddress;
      console.log(Settings.gateIpAddress); <------ UNDEFINED
    });
    electron.settingsApi.read();
  }, []);
```

How I can handle this?

Comment: You cannot use updated state straight after setting it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607037/update-usestate-immediately

Comment: Why static field also doesn't update and why page doesn't rerender?

Comment: There could be many reasons. `FirstComponent` may not run before `SecondComponent`.

Comment: looks like I found the reason and I don't understand =) I'll update the question

Comment: thank you, @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is - I'm stupid =)

When I save settings I did it like this:

```
    const settings = new Settings();
    settings.ipAddress= state.ipAddress;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(settings));
    electron.settingsApi.save(settings);   <------ PASS OBJECT
```

But when I return response it was:

```
ipcMain.on('readSettings', (event, _) => {
  storage.getAll((err: Error, data: object) => {
    if (err) {
      return;
    }
    const { appSettings } = data;
    const settings = new Settings();
    settings.ipAddress= appSettings.ipAddress;
    console.log('reading settings');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(settings));
    event.reply('readSettings', JSON.stringify(settings)); <-------- FACEPALM
  });
});
```

What I can say - genius