# Change handler method for AutoComplete with Checkbox in material UI React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I want to implement a field using `<AutoComplete />` in my form. I get the `options` from a `get` request. And here is the result when I print them in console.

```
[
    {
        "uid": "c34bb0ed-9f63-4803-8639-a42c7e2a8fb0",
        "tag_name": "Food"
    },
    {
        "uid": "346ab2da-e71d-4449-822e-e4836caa7076",
        "tag_name": "Religion"
    },
    {
        "uid": "9b4a9fd5-28fd-4690-8b00-a22c08a7c076",
        "tag_name": "Culture"
    },
    {
        "uid": "7889048e-03d7-4637-9fee-b22f8e7368dd",
        "tag_name": "Nature"
    },
    {
        "uid": "b3809713-b1bc-4676-beec-7637f4ae9183",
        "tag_name": "Native people"
    },
    {
        "uid": "1d84d7a2-13f4-43cd-9b8c-666a68d269d6",
        "tag_name": "My Host"
    }
]
```

But after I click on any of the checkboxes, the item would be disappeared from the select list.
[image]

And also when I see the logs, it seems that the `onChange` method does not work correctly, and the first checked value is not set in `selectedTags` list.
[image]

Here is my code for loading tags:

```
 const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
const loadTags = async () => {
        axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/blog/tags/",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }).then((result) => {
            setTags(result.data.data);
            console.log("********** The Tags are ******** ", tags);
        }).catch((error) => {
            toast.error("Something went wrong while fetching tags.")
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadTags();
    }, []);
```

Here is my code for `AutoComplete` field:

```
const handleTagSelection = (value) => {
        console.log("********** The value is: ***********", value);
        setSelectedTags(value);
        console.log("++++++++ The selected tags are: ++++++++", selectedTags);
    }
<Autocomplete
    clearIcon={false}
    multiple
    id="tags-outlined"
    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.tag_name === value.tag_name}
    options={tags}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.tag_name}
    filterSelectedOptions
    sx={{ width: "50rem" }}
    size="small"
    disableCloseOnSelect
    value={selectedTags}
    noOptionsText="No related tag is available"
    onChange={(e, value) => {
        if (value) {
            handleTagSelection(value);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }}
    renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
        <li {...props}>
            <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={
                selected
            }
            />
            {option.tag_name}
        </li>
        )}
        style={{ width: 500 }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} label="Tags"  />
        )}
/>
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `filterSelectedOptions` attribute from `Autocomplete` component may help.

Reference: [Autocomplete API props](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#props)

Comment: Thanks. Now the checkbox is checked correctly, but the `onChange` handler still does not work, and has the same problem. And the value is not correctly saved in `selectedTags`.

Comment: @NarimanMasjedi `onChange` handler does work. The reason why you see wrong value is: When you call `setSelectedTags`, React doesn't immediately update the value of `selectedTags`, but instead pushes the update into React's update queue to be processed later. Therefore, when you log `selectedTags` inside console.log, you see the value before the update. You can use `useEffect` to console log whenever `selectedTags` is updated, it will give you correct answer.

Comment: @NarimanMasjedi You can check out this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66644538).